# SQLAlchemy get added object's id without committing session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need ID of an object which I've just added using `session.add()`. I need the auto-increment ID of this object before `committing` session.

If I called the object instance.id, I get `None`.

Is there a way to get ID of a object without committing?

Comment: hacky solution but could you get the id of the last object added and just add one?

Comment: The above is really quite risky, could be all sorts of problems. The main question here is /why/ you need the id before commit? for editing? or? There are other ways you could obtain/edit the object

Comment: I need to pass ID of the object to a function which will be called by `celery` at a future time. http://www.celeryproject.org/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Simple answer: call `session.flush()`.

Comment: Thanks. Is it guaranteed to work always and without any side-effects?

Comment: None that commit() would not trigger anyway.